# How do I get this mesh ready for sculpting?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I've just picked up Blender recently and after learning all of the basics, I attempted to make a base mesh for sculpting a Great Maccao (a raptor-like creature from a video game). I've gotten thus far and whenever I attempt to sculpt on it, the results are not pretty. I followed this tutorial, since it has the roughly the same shape in mind (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZnUgt659oI). Any ideas of what I've done wrong? Any and all help is appreciated.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! What kind of results are you seeing exactly? A screenshot of sculpt mode showing the issue would be really helpful.

Comment: is it possible to add a short screencap video of my issue?

Comment: Stack Exchange supports the addition of .gifs to questions, or you can upload a video elsewhere (ex: YouTube) and link it here. A .gif would be best though.

Comment: Thank you. I settled with the screenshot however. hopefully it helps.

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals? Select your mesh, go to edit mode, press A once or twice to select all and press Ctrl+N.

Comment: Ah, it was the normals, my mistake. Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure and it’s difficult to tell with the matcap on but it appears to me that it might be wrong facing normals. Try going back into Edit Mode, selecting all the mesh and pressing “Ctrl+N” to fix the normals. Happy sculpting.